# Calculating sum for each row of the outer index of a multi indexed pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of `seller`, `item`, `price`, `shipping`, `free shipping minimum`, `count available`, and `count needed`. My goal is to find the cheapest combination of `seller` and `item` based on their `total` which is calculated later (code to calculate this is shown below). Sample data is included below:

```
import pandas as pd

item1 = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 1', 'item 1', 'item 2']
seller1 = ['Seller 1', 'Seller 2', 'Seller 3', 'Seller 4', 'Seller 1']
price1 = [1.85, 1.94, 2.00, 2.00, 2.02]
shipping1 = [0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 2.99, 0.99]
freeship1 = [5, 5, 5, 50, 5]
countavailable1 = [1, 2, 2, 5, 2]
countneeded1 = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Seller':seller1,
                    'Item':item1,
                    'Price':price1,
                    'Shipping':shipping1,
                    'Free Shipping Minimum':freeship1,
                    'Count Available':countavailable1,
                    'Count Needed':countneeded1})

# create columns that states if seller has all counts needed.
# this will be used to sort by to prioritize the smallest number of orders possible
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Count Available'] >= row['Count Needed']:
        df1.at[index, 'Fulfills Count Needed'] = 'Yes'
    else:
        df1.at[index, 'Fulfills Count Needed'] = 'No'

# dont want to calc price based on [count available], so need to check if seller has count I need and calc cost based on [count needed].
# if doesn't have [count needed], then calc cost on [count available].
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Count Available'] >= row['Count Needed']:
        df1.at[index, 'Price x Count'] = row['Count Needed'] * row['Price']
    else:
        df1.at[index, 'Price x Count'] = row['Count Available'] * row['Price']
```

However, any one `seller` can sell multiple `item`s. I want to minimize how much shipping is paid, so I want to group `item`s together by `seller`. So I group them based on a way I saw in another thread by using the `.first()` method in order to keep every column in the new grouped dataframe.

```
# Don't calc [Total] until sellers have been grouped
# use first() method to return all columns and perform no other aggregations
grouped1 = df1.sort_values('Price').groupby(['Seller', 'Item']).first()
```

It's at this point I want to calculate the `total` by `seller`. So I have the following code, but it calculates `total` for each `item` as opposed to `seller` which means `shipping` is being added multiple times per seller based on how many items are in each group or free shipping is not being applied when `Price x Count` is over `free shipping minimum`.

```
# calc [Total]
for index, row in grouped1.iterrows():
    if (row['Free Shipping Minimum'] == 50) & (row['Price x Count'] > 50):
        grouped1.at[index, 'Total'] = row['Price x Count'] + 0
    elif (row['Free Shipping Minimum'] == 5) & (row['Price x Count'] > 5):
        grouped1.at[index, 'Total'] = row['Price x Count'] + 0
    else:
        grouped1.at[index, 'Total'] = row['Price x Count'] + row['Shipping']
```

It actually looks like I may need to sum `Price x Count` for each `seller` while calculating `Total`, but that's essentially the same problem since I don't know how to calculate a column per row of the outer index. What methods can I use to do this?

Also, if anyone has any tips on how to tackle the second half of my goal, fire away. I want to return only as many of each item as I need. For example, I need 2 of "item 1" and 2 of "item 2". If "Seller 1" has 2 of "item 1" and 1 of "item 2" while "Seller 2" has 1 of "item 1" and 1 of "item 2", I want everything from "Seller 1" (assuming it is cheapest) but only the 1 "item 1" from "Seller 2". This seems like it will play into calculating the `total` column, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deciding to first groupby `Seller` and sum `Price x Count` to find the `Subtotal`s, convert this into a dataframe, then merging `df1` with the new `subtotal` dataframe to create the `grouped` dataframe. Then I created the `Totals` column using the `np.where` suggestion (which is much more elegant than my for loop and handles NaN values easily). Finally, grouping by `Seller`, `Total`, and `Item` returns the result I wanted. The finalized code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

item1 = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 1', 'item 1', 'item 2']
seller1 = ['Seller 1', 'Seller 2', 'Seller 3', 'Seller 4', 'Seller 1']
price1 = [1.85, 1.94, 2.69, 2.00, 2.02]
shipping1 = [0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 2.99, 0.99]
freeship1 = [5, 5, 5, 50, 5]
countavailable1 = [1, 2, 2, 5, 2]
countneeded1 = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Seller':seller1,
                    'Item':item1,
                    'Price':price1,
                    'Shipping':shipping1,
                    'Free Shipping Minimum':freeship1,
                    'Count Available':countavailable1,
                    'Count Needed':countneeded1})

# create columns that states if seller has all counts needed.
# this will be used to sort by to prioritize the smallest number of orders possible
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Count Available'] >= row['Count Needed']:
        df1.at[index, 'Fulfills Count Needed'] = 'Yes'
    else:
        df1.at[index, 'Fulfills Count Needed'] = 'No'

# dont want to calc price based on [count available], so need to check if seller has count I need and calc cost based on [count needed].
# if doesn't have [count needed], then calc cost on [count available].
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Count Available'] >= row['Count Needed']:
        df1.at[index, 'Price x Count'] = row['Count Needed'] * row['Price']
    else:
        df1.at[index, 'Price x Count'] = row['Count Available'] * row['Price']

# subtotals by seller, then assign calcs to column called [Subtotal] and merge into dataframe
subtotals = df1.groupby(['Seller'])['Price x Count'].sum().reset_index()

subtotals.rename({'Price x Count':'Subtotal'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

grouped = df1.merge(subtotals[['Subtotal', 'Seller']], on='Seller')


# calc [Total]
grouped['Total'] = np.where(grouped['Subtotal'] > grouped['Free Shipping Minimum'],
                             grouped['Subtotal'], grouped['Subtotal'] + grouped['Shipping'])

grouped.groupby(['Seller', 'Total', 'Item']).first()
```

Answer (score 2):

**1 - To answer your first question :**

- Group by seller and then aggregate by summing :

```py
grouped2 = grouped1.groupby('Seller').agg({'Price x Count': 'sum', 'Shipping': 'max'}).reset_index()
###  >>> grouped2
###      Seller  Price x Count  Shipping
### 0  Seller 1           3.87      0.99
### 1  Seller 2           1.94      0.99
### 2  Seller 3           4.00      0.99
### 3  Seller 4           4.00      2.99
```

- Let's define for the show a `Free Shipping Minimum` Column :

```py
# suppose we have the following for the 'Free Shipping Minimum' 
grouped2['Free Shipping Minimum'] = [10,2,2,10]
###  >>> grouped2
###      Seller  Price x Count  Shipping  Free Shipping Minimum
### 0  Seller 1           3.87      0.99                     10
### 1  Seller 2           1.94      0.99                      2
### 2  Seller 3           4.00      0.99                      2
### 3  Seller 4           4.00      2.99                     10
```

- Let's define a `Total` column following this condition : `if 'Price x Count' > 'Free Shipping Minimum' then 'Total' = 'Price x Count' else 'Total' = 'Price x Count' + 'Shipping'` :

```py
grouped2['Total'] = np.where(grouped2['Price x Count'] > grouped2['Free Shipping Minimum'], 
                                  grouped2['Price x Count'], grouped2['Price x Count'] + grouped2['Shipping'])
###  >>> grouped2
###      Seller  Price x Count  Shipping  Free Shipping Minimum  Total
### 0  Seller 1           3.87      0.99                     10   4.86
### 1  Seller 2           1.94      0.99                      2   2.93
### 2  Seller 3           4.00      0.99                      2   4.00
### 3  Seller 4           4.00      2.99                     10   6.99
```

- Items by Seller :

```py
grouped2 = (pd.merge(grouped2, df1.groupby('Seller')['Item']
                                  .agg(', '.join).reset_index(), on='Seller'))
###  >>> grouped2
###      Seller  Price x Count  ...  Total            Item
### 0  Seller 1           3.87  ...   4.86  item 1, item 2
### 1  Seller 2           1.94  ...   2.93          item 2
### 2  Seller 3           4.00  ...   4.00          item 1
### 3  Seller 4           4.00  ...   6.99          item 1
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. `grouped2` sums the shipping when it should only be applied once when calculating the `total`. If "Seller 1" sells both "item 1" and "item 2", shipping should be "0.99" if both items are being purchased, not "1.98". While changing "sum" to "mean" fixes this, I still also need to see what items are being grouped under which `seller`. I'm basically trying to group items into packages and need to be able to see what is in each package.

Comment: Fixed : 'mean' + Items by Seller

Comment: This may be leading to a solution, but it's not quite there yet. I removed your [Total] calc because that was adding [Shipping] before taking into account if [Free Shipping Minimum] came into play. So I replaced [Total Paid] with [Total] and [Total] in the calc with [Price x Count]. This gives the accurate shipping. I then dropped duplicate `Seller`s and merged [Total] into my original dataframe (in this case df1). However, using 'mean' in groupby throws off if a `seller` has listed one `item` with 0.00 `shipping` and another with 1.99 `shipping` for example.

Comment: Even then, I see some `Total`s in my full dataset are being calculated incorrectly. For example, two items with `Price x Count` 1.85 and 2.06  and 0.99 `Shipping` from the same `Seller` have the `Total` 2.84 when it should be 4.90. It seems to have only added the `Shipping` value to the first `Item` and listed that `Total` for both items.

Comment: I agree there was a logic problem on `Total` : fixed. I suggest you the use of `max` instead of `mean`. Plus I simplify function for Items By Seller.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


item1 = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 1', 'item 1', 'item 2']
seller1 = ['Seller 1', 'Seller 2', 'Seller 3', 'Seller 4', 'Seller 1']
price1 = [1.85, 1.94, 2.00, 2.00, 2.02]
shipping1 = [0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 2.99, 0.99]
freeship1 = [5, 5, 5, 50, 5]
countavailable1 = [1, 2, 2, 5, 2]
countneeded1 = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1]


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Seller':seller1,
                    'Item':item1,
                    'Price':price1,
                    'Shipping':shipping1,
                    'Free Shipping Minimum':freeship1,
                    'Count Available':countavailable1,
                    'Count Needed':countneeded1})
```

You can use np.where for filling Fulfills Count Needed with using where instead of for loops. It'll help you to make more clean your code
np.where() method is simle if else statement. np.where(Condition,X,Y). X mean is  if condition true return X, Y mean is if condition wrong return Y.

```
df1['Fulfills Count Needed'] = np.where(df1['Count Available'] >= df1['Count Needed'],"Yes","No")

#Adding pricex count for each item and sellers.

    df1["Price x Count"] = np.where(df1['Count Available'] >= df1['Count Needed'],df1["Count Needed"]*df1["Price"],df1["Count Available"]*df1["Price"])
```

The last versions of item1_df and item2_df are shown below.

```
Seller  Item    Price   Shipping    Free Shipping Minimum   Count Available Count Needed    Fulfills Count Needed   Price x Count   Total   Need_to_pay
    0   Seller 1    item 1  1.85    0.99    5.0     1.0      2.0    1.85    2.84    2.84
    1   Seller 3    item 1  2.00    0.99    5.0     2.0      2.0    4.00    4.99    4.99
    2   Seller 4    item 1  2.00    2.99    50.0    5.0      2.0    4.00    6.99    6.99


    Seller  Item    Price   Shipping    Free Shipping Minimum   Count Available Count Needed    Fulfills Count Needed   Price x Count   Total   Need_to_pay
0   Seller 2    item 2  1.94    0.99    5.0 2.0 1.0 1.94    2.93    2.93
1   Seller 1    item 2  2.02    0.99    5.0 2.0 1.0 2.02    3.01    3.01

item1_needed = "X count"
item2_needed = "Y count"
oredered_df =  pd. DataFrame()

item1_df["Count Needed"], item2_df["Count Needed"] = item1_needed,item2_needed
```

After that step you can use while loop to get min paid information.During while loop, check if the available count is more than what you need or less than what u need. If is less than what you need get all available count and add your ordered_df with seller, item and how much paid columns.

Update your item1_needed and keep continue that till item1_needed = 0

Repeat same steeps for item1

Last part check if you paid more to same sellers for shipping.
If you paid more remove overpaid.